# Error -2147417848 Automation error The object invoked has disconnected from its clients

Tags: excel, runtime-error, excel-2010, vba

I am working on clearing some tables in 3 excel sheets.

My code was working fine with Excel 2007, as i switched to excel 2010 i started getting this runtime error **Automation error The object invoked has disconnected from its clients**, error number **-2147417848** and then excel freezes.

the error is showing after running this function 2 times on the line

```
    Sheets("Risk Details").Range("A3" & ":BV" & (count + 1)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

can anyone help me in finding out why this is happening and how to work around it?

below are the full code for the function

```
Function clearData(Optional refresh As Boolean) As Boolean
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Single Risk Register").Unprotect myPass
Sheets("Single Risk Register").Activate
Cells.FormatConditions.Delete


Sheets("Risk Details").Unprotect myPass
Sheets("Risks").Unprotect myPass
Dim currentrange As Range


Sheets("Risks").Activate
Set currentrange = Sheets("Risks").Range("RisksTable")
currentrange.ClearContents


Dim count As Integer
count = Sheets("Risks").ListObjects("RisksTable").ListRows.count
If count > 1 Then
    Sheets("Risks").Range("A3" & ":C" & (count + 1)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
End If


Sheets("Risk Details").Activate
Set currentrange = Sheets("Risk Details").Range("RiskDetails")
currentrange.ClearContents
count = Sheets("Risk Details").ListObjects("RiskDetails").ListRows.count
If count > 1 Then
    Sheets("Risk Details").Range("A3" & ":BV" & (count + 1)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
End If
Sheets("Single Risk Register").Activate
count = CInt(Range("ActionsCount"))
Range("ActionsCount") = 1

Dim tableLastRow As Integer
tableLastRow = getLastTableRow()
If (tableLastRow >= 48) Then
    Sheets("Single Risk Register").Range("B48" & ":K" & tableLastRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp
End If
Range("ActionsTable[[Action Description]:[Action Commentary]]").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim DataRange As Range

Dim o As Shape
Dim tC As Variant
Dim propertiesCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer

tC = Sheets("TableColumns").ListObjects("TableColumns").DataBodyRange

propertiesCount = GetTemplatePropertiesCount(templates(0)) - 1
ReDim properties(0 To propertiesCount - 1, 0 To 4)
If (properitesColl.Item(i + 1)(propertiesCount, 2) = templates(0)) Then
    properties = properitesColl.Item(i + 1)
End If

For count = 0 To propertiesCount - 1
    If ((properties(count, 4) <> "C25") And (properties(count, 4) <> "C26") And (properties(count, 4) <> "C27") And (properties(count, 4) <> "C28") And (properties(count, 4) <> "C38") And (properties(count, 4) <> "C39") And (properties(count, 4) <> "C40") And (properties(count, 4) <> "C41"))

    Then
        Sheets("Single Risk Register").Range(properties(count, 4)) = ""
    End If
Next

Dim columnCount As Integer
columnCount = GetColumnCount()
count = 0
For i = 1 To columnCount
    If tC(i, 4) <> "Action" Then
        Set currentrange = Range(tC(i, 4))
    Else
        Set currentrange = Range("ActionsTable[" & tC(i, 1) & "]")
    End If
    If ((tC(i, 4) = "C25") Or (tC(i, 4) = "C26") Or (tC(i, 4) = "C27") Or (tC(i, 4) = "C28") Or (tC(i, 4) = "C38") Or (tC(i, 4) = "C39") Or (tC(i, 4) = "C40") Or (tC(i, 4) = "C41")) 

     Then
        With currentrange.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 15654866
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With

    Else
        With currentrange.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
            .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
Next


Sheets("Single Risk Register").Unprotect myPass
If (Range("C3").Value = "") Then
    Range("ActionsTable[[Action Description]:[" & addTitle & "]]").Select
    Selection.Locked = True
    Rows("45:47").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If


Sheets("Single Risk Register").Range(Range("TitleCell")).Value = Range("OldTitle") + " (" + Range("Project_Title") + ")"

Sheets("Single Risk Register").Protect myPass, AllowFiltering:=True
Sheets("Risk Details").Protect myPass, AllowFiltering:=True
Sheets("Risks").Protect myPass, AllowFiltering:=True

doNotRun = False
Range("C3").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Function

err:  

Sheets("Risk Details").Protect myPass
Sheets("Risks").Protect myPass
MsgBox err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
```

Comment: Maybe it's me but, it would really help making code more easy to read (a)

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319832 - from that link, **If the code always appears to work the first time that it is run, and if the errors or the unexpected behaviors occur only during subsequent calls to the same code, an unqualified method call is the cause.**

Comment: Do you have any alm related add ins installed in excel?

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft provide a high-level answer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319832):

If the code always appears to work the first time that it is run, and if the errors or the unexpected behaviors occur only during subsequent calls to the same code, an unqualified method call is the cause.

Comment: That link no longer works. You can view the page here instead: http://web.archive.org/web/20140706022502/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319832