# Object invoked has disconnected from its clients when inserting row

Tags: vba, excel

I keep getting a

> Object invoked has disconnected from its clients

from running this line

```
Workbooks("LastParamChanges").Sheets("LastChanges").Range("A9").EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
```

When the error message pops up and I click debug to go to that line, I click <kbd>F8</kbd> to continue to the next line, another error message pops up saying

> Runtime Error 1004: Insert method of Range class has failed

I also have `Application.DisplayAlerts` and `Application.EnableEvents` set to False if that helps.

Comment: Are you certain that a workbook with name "`LastParamChanges`" is opened and not ReadOnly before that line of code?

Comment: Yep, the thing is the code fails after a while, not the first time it's run, so I'm not sure what's going on

Comment: (1) If you search for "excel vba Object invoked has disconnected from its clients", you will get many hits discussing this issue. I found the link from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14831492/973283) particularly helpful in understanding the issue. What is happening between uses of this statement? Could you have closed the workbook or renamed the worksheet?

Comment: (2) I would not set `Application.DisplayAlerts` to `False` since this means you are not warned about an issue. I only use it when my code deletes a worksheet and I do not want the user to have to confirm the delete. (3) I always use the full name of a workbook including the extension: `Workbooks("LastParamChanges.xlsx")`.

Comment: We cannot tell what went wrong if we cannot see full code. Try search your code for `.Close`. Have you tried step through your code?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution that worked for me was to add this code before the `.Insert` statement:

```
Dim oldValue As Variant
With Workbooks("LastParamChanges").Sheets("LastChanges")
  .Range("B1").Activate
  oldValue = .Range("B1").Value
  .Range("B1").ClearContents
  .Range("B1").Value = oldValue
End With
```

It seems that you first need to edit the sheet before inserting any rows.